# Heroku App Not Properly Formatted Even After Precompile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have just created a personal website with specific css styling. Sources online have said to precompile my assets before deployment, after following those directions my heroku app is still not properly formatted.

any insights?

my gemfile looks like this:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
     gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
     gem 'pg'

     gem 'rails_12factor'

     group :development, :test do
       gem 'sqlite3'
     end

    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
      gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
      gem 'jquery-rails'

      gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
      gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

      gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
   # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
      gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
      gem 'json'

   # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
   # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

   # Use Unicorn as the app server
   # gem 'unicorn'

   # Use Capistrano for deployment
   # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

   group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a    debugger console
   gem 'byebug'

   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
   gem 'spring'
    end
```

and my database.yml file:

```
     default: &default
     adapter: postgresql
     pool: 5
     timeout: 5000

     development:
     <<: *default
     database: db/development





       test:
         <<: *default
       database: db/test

       production:
               <<: *default
         database: db/production
```

Thanks

Edit:

By 'not formatted properly' I mean that my styles are not present.

```
      /*
      * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into     application.css, which will include all the files
      * listed below.
      *
      * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
      * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
      *
      * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
      * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
      * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
     * file per style scope.
     *
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
     */


     html, body{
     background:#eeecec; 
     background-image:url("clown_station.png");
     background-size:cover;
     text-align:none;
     }

     h1{
     font-family:'Helvetica';
     font-weight:bold;
     color:black;
     }

     .kowabunga_logo{
     position:absolute;
     left:200px;
      }

     .site-container {
     background-color:#ffffff;
     border-right:0;
     border-bottom:0;
     top:0;
     display:block;
     overflow:auto;
     background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
     width:84%;
     }



     .site-container{
      position:absolute;
      top:185px;
      right:97px;
      width:85%;
      height:75%;
      box-shadow:0 2px 2px 1px rgba(64,64,65,.11)
      }

     .kowabunga_bar{
      height:30px;
      background-color:#3f3f3f;
      z-index:-1;
      font-family:'Indie Flower', cursive;
      }

      .kowabunga_bar p{
      float:left;
      margin-left:5px;
      margin-top:5px;
      }

      .kowabunga_bar img{
      z-index:100; /*position: relative;*/
      position:inline;
      float:right;
      margin-right:5px;
      margin-top:2px;
      }

      .kowabunga_bar #contact{
      z-index:100; 
      position:inline;
      float:right;
      margin-right:10px;
      margin-top:5px;
      }

    #tweet_pic {
    z-index:100;
    position:inline;
    float:right;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-left:920px;
    }

    #tweet{
    z-index:100; 
    position:inline;
    float:right;
    }

       #navigation{
       position:absolute;
       top:195px;
       left:97px;
       }


    ul#navigation {
    padding:0;
    z-index:1;
    }

    ul#navigation li {
     display:inline;
     }

    ul#navigation li a {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

      ul#navigation li a:hover {
      color:#5ac9de;
      }

    #list_item img{
    display:block;
    height:90px;
    width:148px;
    }

     #list_title{
     border-bottom:1px solid gray;
     }

    .social_media{
    margin-left:1050px;
    margin-top:0px;
    border-top-width:50px;
    padding-top:4px;
    }

      #neon_cover{
      position: absolute;
      right: 1px;
      bottom: 300px;
      }
```

Comment: What element of formatting is incorrect?  Is the site live so that we can look at it?  Is there a reference available for how it should look?

Comment: If by "not properly formatted" you mean your styles aren't present, you should include the contents of application.css as well as the file structure of your assets/stylesheets folder.

Comment: thanks, yes, I meant 'styles aren't present'. I just included the contents of application.css